# WordPress using Fullscreen Galleria to display ImPress Listings images

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using IMPress listings to display manually display Real Estate Listings. For the single listings there is a wysiwyg for adding images for the image gallery one at a time.

[image]

These output using

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_listing_gallery', true)); ?>
```

I would like to use [Fullscreen Galleria](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/fullscreen-galleria/) to display the images. I here is what I tried. This doesn't work because the shortcode requires image ids.

```
echo do_shortcode('[fsg_link class="btn-primary" include="' . get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_listing_gallery', true) . '"]View Full Screen[/fsg_link]');
```

It appears that this particular short code requires image id's and not HTML.

What would be the best way to display image ids so it outputs like so

```
echo do_shortcode('[fsg_link class="btn-primary" include="501,502,503"]View Full Screen[/fsg_link]');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions.php

```
function pippin_get_image_id($image_url) {
        global $wpdb;
       $attachment = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_url )); 
return $attachment[0]; 
}
```

Page Template

```
    if (get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_listing_gallery', true) != '') { 

        $image_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_listing_gallery', true);
        $doc = new DOMDocument;
        $doc->loadHTML($image_url);
        $galleryimg = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

        $images = array();

        foreach ($galleryimg as $galleryimg){

            $galleryimg = $galleryimg->getAttribute('src');             
            $image_id = pippin_get_image_id($galleryimg);
            array_push($images, $image_id);                 
            $string = rtrim(implode(',', $images), ',');

    }

    echo do_shortcode('[fsg_link class="btn-primary" include="' . $string . '"]View Full Screen[/fsg_link]');
```